# How to package python dependencies properly

Tags: python, vim

I'm currently writing a Vim plugin in python that depends on certain python packages (selenium and requests).

Vim has its own python built in. So, even though I'm writing a plugin in python, a user might not necessarily have python installed.

I can think of 2 options:

1. Ship the packages as part of the repository (either through git submodules or just manually with `pip -target`/venv)

   - This seems like it's wrong. The dependencies would be static and have to be manually updated.
2. Assume python and pip are already installed and use these to install the dependencies to the plugin directory

   - This requires the user to have python and pip installed. I would rather not assume that python is available. Additionally, could there be any issues with python versioning (as there might be a different version between installed python and vim python)?

Am I missing anything? 
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should not trigger `pip` from vim. The end-user may not be able to install, or may not want to install things in his python environment. I'd be extremely annoyed with such a Vim plugin.

Instead, I'd would clearly document which Python packages are required, and test whether they are available when your plugin is loaded. From here, you could either silently disable the plugin, or emit a warning, or run in a degraded mode...

For instance, I use the [following test](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/python.vim#L89) when I need non-usual Python packages.

```
function! lh#python#can_import(module) abort
  let flavour = lh#python#best_still_avail()
  if empty(flavour) | return 0 | endif
  try
    exe flavour.' import '.a:module
  catch /.*/
    return 0
  endtry
    return 1
endfunction
```

NB: `lh#python#best_still_avail()` is another function that tries to detect whether we are using python 2 or 3. If you always use `:pyx`, `:python` or `:python3`, you could simply use `exe 'pyx import '.a:module` instead.

Comment: I'd understand your annoyance. But I was thinking of using pip -target (maybe with venv) to make sure that it doesn't affect the user's global python environment.

Comment: Also, I just had a look at https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe and they seem to just use git submodules. The issue with that is how are they setup? Is there a way to change a package+dependencies into git submodules? If I did it that way, I wouldn't want to do that manually

Comment: Regarding venv, what if the user is already within a venv? Regarding submodules, and solution 1., I don't know, I leave other people (to?) expressing their opinion of this solution.